# RDP with VPN freeze the screen

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop

coming directly to the point, I am using vpn to connect with one customer and after that accessing productive machine through RDP.
Every thing was working very fine but from the last month, the RDP machine screen freeze.
It's successfully login but just after few seconds the complete screen is freeze.
Here are my Windows updates list

[windows update list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsGiz.png)

I am using Sophos SSL (having not problem in vpn connection).
I am happy, if someone helps me in this regards,
Thank you
N. Stefen

Comment: From my experience this may be a firewall blocking the RDP UDP traffic in one direction (can happen randomly after minutes or hours). But a problem on RDP UDP transport layer would also be possible. In such a case the screen freezes but you can still perform actions blind. You can force RDP client or server to use TCP only for RDP via group policy.

Comment: It did it via group policy but it's now helping....

Comment: Have you executed `gpupdate /force` to be sure that the GPO has been applied?

Comment: that's i did not... how can i do that? just from cmd or somewhere else?